# Manual update without database backup

Tags: database, updating, manual-updates

I’m trying to update Craft Pro 2.0.2543 to the latest build but the site’s database is in excess of 2Gb. When hitting ‘Finish up’ in the CP after a manual update, by the time the database has backed up I’m logged out, or the process has timed out. Is there a way I can ‘Finish up’ without the backup running first?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is indeed possible. Craft has a handy general configuration option for this exact situation.

```
return array(

    'backupDbOnUpdate' => false 

);
```

Just add that to `config/general.php` and that should do the trick!

Comment: Other really useful config settings [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings) too :)